# Method of proof for inequalities

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that

$n+4<7n^2$ knowing that $n\in N\setminus\{0\}$

So far I've only seen the proof by induction, which seems useless in this scenario.

If I rewrite it $4<7n^2 - n$, it seems obvious that since $n^2>n$ for all $n<>1$ and that `7n > n`, the inequation must be true. But how can I *prove* it?

I thought that using the proof by contradiction would be a good idea, so I started working with this.

$n+4>7n^2$

I can test this inequality using `n=1` and prove it is `false`.

$1+4 > 7*1^2$ is false.

Is this enough to prove that $n+4<7n^2$?

Comment: You could use quadratic equation.
And also use math.induction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by induction. The induction step goes as follows:

$ (n+1) + 4 < 7(n+1)^2$

$ (n+1) + 4 < 7(n^2+2n+1) = 7n^2 + (14n+7)$

And since we may assume in our induction step the hypotheses:

$ n+4 < 7n^2 $

we come to the equation:

$ 1 < 14n + 7$

which clearly is true for all $n>0$.

Of course the initial case $n=1$ is trivial.

Comment: Shouldn't the equation be $7n^2+(14n+7)$ instead of $7n^2+(14n+1)$? But thanks to you, it was pretty easy in the end! :)

Comment: Oh dear, of course, I will edit =)